# Django can't find social auth url pattern

Tags: python, django, steam-web-api, social-authentication

I have tried to set up social authentication for steam login button. I have followed all [these steps](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/django.html), and added steam necessary stuff: adding API key to settings and `steam.SteamOpenId` to authentication backends.

The error:

> ```
> Using the URLconf defined in Test.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
> ^ ^$ [name='index']
> ^login/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='begin']
> ^complete/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='complete']
> ^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/$ [name='disconnect']
> ^disconnect/(?P<backend>[^/]+)/(?P<association_id>[^/]+)/$ [name='disconnect_individual']
> ^admin/
> ```

Hyperlink i used to make login button:

```
<a href="/login/steam?next=/">Login</a>
```

`urls.py` file of project:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('Home.urls')),
    url('', include('social.apps.django_app.urls', namespace='social')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

`urls.py` file of application `Home`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

app_name = 'Home'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

[Full Project Here.](https://github.com/ShellRox/PSA)

I am wondering if there is still something that i need to set up, do i need to add views to url patterns? If so, then which? where is social authentication urls file located?

Comment: Do you have `APPEND_SLASH` in your settings set to `False`? If so, Django will not redirect `/login/steam` to `/login/steam/`. If that's not the issue, can you post the complete traceback and the relevant `urls.py` files?

Comment: @knbk I couldn't find anything relevant to `APPEND_SLASH` in `settings.py` file, Is there something wrong?

Comment: Then that is not the issue, the default is `True`. It would explain your problem, but apparently there's a different cause for the behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: added the data of projects urls.py file and application's manually created urls.py file @knbk

Comment: Just to confirm: if you add a trailing slash to the url, so it becomes `/login/steam/?next=/`, does it still not work?

Comment: It doesn't work, I have tried accessing /login/ pattern itself, but still gave me 404 response. @knbk